# как подать на вход python скрипту параметры из текстового файла?

Tags: python, stdin

```
$python3 script.py -param | cat string.txt
```

как можно сделать нечто похожее? мой пример не работает

Comment: Вот [тут](https://jenyay.net/Programming/Argparse) почитайте

Comment: Вообще задача интересная, если бы и вопрос был задан понятно...

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью модуля sys читать стандартный ввод:

*params.txt*:

```
one
two
three
```

*frompipe.py*

```
import sys
for param in enumerate(sys.stdin.readlines()):
    print(f"param number {param[0]} - {param[1]}")
```

в командной строке:

```
cat params.txt | python frompipe.py
```

вывод:

```
param number 0 - one

param number 1 - two

param number 2 - three
```